# pthread_create creates SIGSEGV on linux x64

Tags: c, pthreads

I am currently working with ncurses.h on my MacBook.
On there, everything runs fine. I now wanted to test it on my linux laptop.
When the program tries to creat the thread, it crashes.

I do it like this:

```
    pthread_create(&draw_thread,NULL,draw_thread_func,NULL);
    pthread_detach(draw_thread);
```

I have no idea why its crashing on linux, since its working on my macbook

I expect it to not crash

Comment: More context please. What does the main thread do afterwards? What does `pthread_create` return?

Comment: @mch so i am using it with nucrses. The draw_thread draws the content on the screen (texts,...) and the main thread is handlich keyboard input with `getch()` and a while loop. I create set it to detached, so that the main thread is not waiting on the draw thread. 
i can't say, what pthread_create returns, since it does not even reach the point to print it :/

Comment: So it does not even come to the `pthread_detach`? What happens when you replace the `draw_thread_func` by a simpler function, which just prints something and returns? Does it help when you compile with `-fsanitize=address -g`?

Comment: Did you run it in a debugger and check where exactly the crash happens? Please do not describe your code but show it.

Comment: i ran it in the debugger, and it was acutally a problem with a pointer of mine *inside* the method, that the thread executes. I ran it through gdb before, but i think that i set my brake-point at the wrong spot :D Thanks for the help tho!

can someone recommend a book about gdb and how to use it correctly?

Comment: I can recommend to use your IDE to debug your application instead of directly using gdb.

Comment: What IDE would you recommend? VS? Code::Blocks? I do need to run cross-platform, since i work on mac and windows :O i am currently using vscode